# Slow start times for FileZilla with disconnected network drives

Tags: windows-8, filezilla

I have been using FileZilla for about 3 years (currently on Windows 8), and recently I have started getting slow startup times. I did some research, and I found that others had also had issues with it and it pertained to having mapped network drives that were disconnected/not powered up, and when I removed them, it started up immediately.

Sadly, I cannot have these network drives removed as they account for my entire storage needs when I am in the office, and my local network when I am at home, so wherever I go, there will always be disconnected network drives. So, is there a way to circumvent FileZilla's need to check all the drives, perhaps limiting it to only have access to the C drive on my computer?

Comment: I wouldn't expect this to have user-level solution. Sounds rather like semi-bug, so you should better report this to Filezilla authors.

Comment: I am in the process of doing this at the moment, but is there any way of configuring windows to have network shares that do not get accessed in the typical way, with 3rd party software to access the share, and create a mount in `my computer` that when access is attempted an it is not available, it is empty

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a slow startup and used WireShark to investigate what FileZilla is doing.  I found it was using SMB (Samba) calls to query every file and folder in the last local path I had open before I closed FileZilla.  So if your path was a mapped drive like x:\dir1\dir2\dir3 when you closed it, it will query every file and folder in root () then every file and folder in \dir1, then \dir1\dir2 and finally \dir\dir2\dir3 when you reopen it.  This is a lot of slow activity and in my case took about a minute or so to complete.  My solution was to enter c:\ as the local directory before closing it.  Next time you start it up it opens almost immediately.